# How to say that a word sounds impolite

Tags: grammar

I want to say:

> The word 'foreigner' sounds a little impolite.

These are my attempts:

> foreignerという言葉はちょっと無礼そうです。
>   foreignerという言葉はちょっと無礼に見えます。
>   foreignerという言葉はちょっと無礼に聞こえます。

Are any of these correct? Should I prefer one form over another when I'm talking about speech or writing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the last one is the best, I'd probably use 失礼｛しつれい｝though.

> 「Foreigner」という言葉はちょっと失礼に聞こえます。

Other examples could be:

「Foreigner」という言葉はちょっと失礼な響きがあると思います。

「Foreigner」という言葉はちょっと失礼です。